# How come crontab -e is different from less /etc/crontab?

Tags: cron

Im pretty new to unix and crons, I was currently about to try to add crons to an existing cron file. I read you could do this with `crontab -e`. The confusing thing to me is just that `crontab -e` shows different crons/commands than `less /etc/crontab` - how come? Which one is the correct way/file to edit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although @X Tian's answer contains info on the different files for crontab, the essential information concerning your question is this:

`crontab -e` edits the user's crontab file (stored in the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` directory on current Debian systems, but YMMV) or creates a new one, and not `/etc/crontab`. Similar for `crontab -l` (list crontab file) and `crontab -r` (remove crontab file).

For all cron jobs that should be executed under a user's account, you should use `crontab -e`. For system jobs, you should add a file under `/etc/cron.d`, if that exists; under `/etc/cron.{hourly|daily|weekly|monthly}` (but those must not be named like a package name!), if that fits your purpose; or add a line to `/etc/crontab`. But be aware that `/etc/crontab` might be overwritten with a system update.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas Thank you for clarifying with your edit. The `/var/spool/cron/` directory is a Linux specialty (see  the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARSPOOLCRONCRONANDATJOBS)) and the location may vary on systems other than a current Debian.

Answer (score 4):

You really want to read the manual pages `man cron` and `man crontab`

Here is an extract which covers your question. From `man cron`

> NOTES
>          cron searches its spool  area  (/var/spool/cron/crontabs)  for  crontab
>          files  (which  are named after accounts in /etc/passwd); crontabs found
>          are loaded into memory.  Note that crontabs in  this  directory  should
>          not be accessed directly - the crontab command should be used to access
>          and update them.
>
> ```
>    cron also reads /etc/crontab, which is in a slightly  different  format
>    (see  crontab(5)).   Additionally, cron reads the files in /etc/cron.d:
>    it treats  the  files  in  /etc/cron.d  as  in  the  same  way  as  the
>    /etc/crontab  file  (they  follow the special format of that file, i.e.
>    they  include  the  user  field).  However,  they  are  independent  of
>    /etc/crontab:  they  do  not, for example, inherit environment variable
>    settings from it. The intended purpose of  this  feature  is  to  allow
>    packages  that  require  finer  control  of  their  scheduling than the
>    /etc/cron.{daily,weekly,monthly} directories to add a crontab  file  to
>    /etc/cron.d. Such files should be named after the package that supplies
>    them. Files must conform to the same naming convention as used by  run-
>    parts(8):  they  must  consist solely of upper- and lower-case letters,
>    digits, underscores, and hyphens. If the -l option is  specified,  then
>    they must conform to the LSB namespace specification, exactly as in the
>    --lsbsysinit option in run-parts.
> ```

Comment: You should specify which cron implementation and which version thereof on which OS and which version thereof you're quoting that from. `cron` is something that varies a lot from OS to OS and on some you can choose between several implementations.