# Crontab CentOS blank output .txt file

Tags: cron

i am configuring cronjob to output every minute but it ended up having an empty txt file (hello.txt) in root. These are the files and codes used:

Testcron.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

/root/libvmi/examples/Test1 TestVM1
```

vi /etc/crontab:

```
* * * * * root /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt
```

Am i doing it correctly? Please help.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of the `Testcron.sh` file when you execute manually?

Comment: Revise `root /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt` to be `root /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt 2>errors.txt` so that you capture any error output.

Comment: @tachomi The output of Testcron.sh is the process list and the domain information of the Guest VM, for this instance, it is TestVM1. I am able to run at command line but have no idea why i can't do it when it is placed as a cronjob :(

Comment: @steve Managed to capture the error output stating that there is a path error for /root/libvmi/examples/Test1 to open. What i normally do for that error is: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib 
is this counted as a path? if do, may i know which file should i put this file in? 
Thanks! :)

Comment: Joy, based on the result from steve's suggestion, you should add that LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib in front of the /root/libvmi/examples/Test1 command (or on the line above it).

Comment: Thanks for the help all! Managed to solve it after checking what error is it about. The error is with regards to the library path and after placing in the path, it works! Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Capturing the comments into a bona fide answer for this question)

@steve suggested:

> Revise `root /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt` to be `root /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt 2>errors.txt` so that you capture any error output

From which @Joy saw that there was an error, and they needed to set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

before running the Test1 command. The resulting Testcron.sh file is then:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
/root/libvmi/examples/Test1 TestVM1
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try running `crontab -e` command as `root` and setup your job there?

```
# crontab -e
* * * * * /root/Testcron.sh >> hello.txt
```

It's not recommended to edit `/etc/crontab` file. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119481/how-come-crontab-e-is-different-from-less-etc-crontab) you can see the difference between `crontab -e` & editing `/etc/creontab` file.

From [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

> This file could be used for other cron commands, but probably shouldn't be. Here's an example line from a ficticious /etc/crontab `00 01 * * * rusty /home/rusty/rusty-list-files.sh` This would run Rusty's command script as user rusty from his home directory. However, it is not usual to add commands to this file. While an experienced user should know about it, it is not recommended that you add anything to /etc/crontab. Apart from anything else, this could cause problem if the /etc/crontab file is affected by updates! Rusty could lose his command.